# What is the best way to check if the value of a function's arguments match specified possibilities?

Tags: r, type-safety, dynamic-typing

Say I have a very simple function that checks the value of an and behaves differently depending if it matches one of a number of possibilities. Here's a minimal example:

```r
is_duck <- function(x) {
  if (x == 'duck') return("QUACK")
  else return("That's not a duck!")
}
```

This works well enough as long as I behave with what I pass my function. But R is dynamically typed, so it's a lawless land out there. I *want* `x == DUCK` to be a length-1 logical vector which I can throw into my branching logic, but I can't guarantee it will be. Is there a better, more type-safe way to accomplish the behavior I want?

I thought about `if(identical(x, 'duck'))` but that would fail in the case that x has some additional attribute, which is a little *too* specific (i.e., `x <- set_names('duck')` would return "That's not a duck!" even though it is). Is `isTRUE(x == 'duck')` what I'm looking for?

Comment: If you need case insensitive, convert it to a lower or upper case inside `if(tolower(x) == 'duck')`

Comment: Is it that you really want x == 'duck' that's okay, but I think more likely if you are concerned about type, you should think  about using `class()` or `typeof()` depending on how strict you want to be.

Comment: If you want type safety, use S4. I doubt you really NEED type safety that much, though